# slider in iphone display

Tags: html, jquery-ui, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to reduce the the width of slider using boot strap responsive css to display it in iphone
but i am not able to do it
can you please help me with it
http://jsfiddle.net/CXkQp/4/

screenshot
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3IBJKENGE7RQkk1eEI3TDNoN2c/edit

providing my code below

```
<div id="banner" class="clearfix" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #cacaca;">
          <div class="bx-wrapper" style="width:100%; position:relative; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
              <div class="bx-window" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; width:100%">

                <div class="container">

                                <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; height: 300px; background-position: 247950% 0%;">
                                  <div class="da-slide da-slide-toleft" style="width: 100%">
                                    <h2><img src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate1A.jpg" alt="image01"></h2>
                                    <div class="da-img"><img src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate1B.jpg" alt="image01"></div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="da-slide da-slide-toleft" style="width: 100%">
                                    <h2><img src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate2A.jpg" alt="image01"></h2>
                                    <div class="da-img"><img src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate2B.jpg" alt="image01"></div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="da-slide da-slide-fromright da-slide-current" style="width: 100%;">
                                    <h2><img src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate3A.jpg" alt="image01"></h2>
                                    <div class="da-img"><img src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate3B.jpg" alt="image01"></div>
                                  </div>
                                  <nav class="da-arrows" style="width: 100%">
                                    <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
                                    <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
                                  </nav>
                                <nav class="da-dots"><span class=""></span><span class=""></span><span class="da-dots-current"></span></nav></div>
                                  </div>

              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of points to get you started. In your jsFiddle, there doesn't seem to be a closing tag for your container div @ line 120.

Also you want your slider to scale but it's not inside a fluid row div.  I think your bootstrap grid needs work. Check the structure for fluid grid carefully: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you are having a hard time getting this to work, start by simplifying the problem. Get a basic responsive grid working, then try adding the slider to that. Then post an update if you need more help. There are too many unknowns for me to jump into this as it stands. Good luck